# Переменная не изменяет свое значение после выхода из метода

Tags: python

Есть метод, в котором проверяется истинность пути и изменение значения переменной.

Проблема с которой я столкнулся:
Переменная checkTypeBool после выполнения метода содержит в себе значение False, хотя путь существует.
Вопрос: как мне изменить значение переменной в методе, что бы после завершения выполнения метода в переменой содержалось True?

```
pathDesktop = "C:\\Users\\batth\\Desktop"
pathTrash = "H:\\Trash"
#Должна изменяться в зависимости от того существует ли путь
checkTypeBool = False

#Только для красивого вывода в консоль
tableInfoPath = PrettyTable(["Dekstop Path"])

def checkPath(path, checkTypeBool):
    #Проверка на существования пути
    if os.path.exists(path):
        tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDesktop + " : Path exists"])
        #Изменяем значение переменной, на true, если путь существует
        checkTypeBool = True
        print(tableInfoPath)
    else:
        tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDekstop + " : Path not found"])

checkPath(pathDesktop, False)
#В итоге получаем, что checkTypeBool = False, хотя я ожидаю True
print(checkTypeBool)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для присвоения глобальным переменным в функциях нужно использовать оператор **global**, иначе это будет создание новой переменной в области действия функции. Кст, я убрал параметр `checkTypeBool` из функции.

Попробуйте:

```
checkTypeBool = False

#Только для красивого вывода в консоль
tableInfoPath = PrettyTable(["Dekstop Path"])

def checkPath(path):
    global checkTypeBool
    #Проверка на существования пути
    if os.path.exists(path):
        tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDesktop + " : Path exists"])
        #Изменяем значение переменной, на true, если путь существует
        checkTypeBool = True
        print(tableInfoPath)
    else:
        tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDekstop + " : Path not found"])

checkPath(pathDesktop)
#В итоге получаем, что checkTypeBool = False, хотя я ожидаю True
print(checkTypeBool)
```

Кст, глобальные переменные не рекомендуются -- они усложняют логику программ. Лучше верните значение из функции:

```
#Только для красивого вывода в консоль
tableInfoPath = PrettyTable(["Dekstop Path"])

def checkPath(path) -> bool:
    #Проверка на существования пути
    if os.path.exists(path):
        tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDesktop + " : Path exists"])
        print(tableInfoPath)
        return True

    tableInfoPath.add_row([pathDekstop + " : Path not found"])
    return False

checkTypeBool = checkPath(pathDesktop)
print(checkTypeBool)
```

Comment: "Кст"? не хило вы целых 6 букв сэкономили за ответ!